# How to query the ApplicationUserManager for custom data that's not exposed by its API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, asp.net-identity

I added the following new property to the `ApplicationUser` class.

```
[ForeignKey("UserTypeId")]
public UserType Type { get; set; }
public int UserTypeId { get; set; }
```

How, I would like to add a new method to the `ApplicationUserManager` to get the *type* of a user like so:

```
public UserType GetUserType()
{
  return null;
}
```

I am assuming that I cannot use the `Store` (`IUserStore<...>`) property of the `ApplicationUserManager` class to query about this new field because I am assuming there is no method that lets me get my own custom fields for a user out of the `IUserStore`.

So, is the only way then to query custom data from the `ApplicationUserManager` class then to create a new `ApplicationDbContext` and get the data yourself?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your `ApplicationUserManager` class is defining your `ApplicationUser` in the `UserManager` generic you should be able to just call the base methods.

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
```

Since the UserManager returns a generic for the User you can simply call methods such as ...

- FindByIdAsync(TKey)
- FindByNameAsync(String)

These methods will return an ApplicationUser including your custom properties.

Alternatively if you are only concerned with the type property and not the whole user object then you can just create your own implementation of the `UserStore` and pass this over when initialising your `ApplicationUserManager` and will you have access to the `DbContext`!

Let me know if you want me to expand on anything or if you need any examples.

Comment: I understand all that you said. I probably should spend some more time articulating my question. I will do that tomorrow. Lack of sleep now.